# XmlPullParser does not see DOCDECL elements

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I'm using an XML pull parser to read XML files, and I want to read the DocDecl element (the  at the begining of the file.

Here's the code I'm using,

```
FileInputStream inputStream;
XmlPullParserFactory factory;
XmlPullParser xpp;
XmlNode document;

inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, true);
xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(inputStream, null);

int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

    switch (eventType) {
    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
        Log.i("Test XML", "START_DOCUMENT");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT:
        Log.i("Test XML", "END_DOCUMENT");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
        Log.i("Test XML", "START_TAG");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
        Log.i("Test XML", "END_TAG");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
        Log.i("Test XML", "TEXT");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.CDSECT:
        Log.i("Test XML", "CDSECT");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.ENTITY_REF:
        Log.i("Test XML", "ENTITY_REF");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE:
        Log.i("Test XML", "IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION:
        Log.i("Test XML", "PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.COMMENT:
        Log.i("Test XML", "COMMENT");
        break;
    case XmlPullParser.DOCDECL:
        Log.i("Test XML", "DOCDECL");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    eventType = xpp.nextToken();
}
```

And here's the result logcat I get :

START_DOCUMENT
START_TAG
START_TAG
TEXT
END_TAG
START_TAG
TEXT
END_TAG
COMMENT
END_DOCUMENT

with the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item>Some text</item>
    <item>Some other text</item>
    <!-- Here's a comment -->
</root>
```

I'm using the FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, as well as the nextToken() to be sure to read everything, yet the DocDecl is not processed. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistook the DOCDECL token for the  tag at the beggining of an xml file, but it is used for DOCTYPE Declaration.

To achieve what I wanted, get the version, encoding and such from the xml, the following code can be used :

```
public static final String PROPERTY_XML_VERSION = "http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#xmldecl-version";
public static final String PROPERTY_XML_STANDALONE = "http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#xmldecl-standalone";

// [...] 

int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
}

String version = (String) xpp.getProperty(PROPERTY_XML_VERSION);
Boolean standalone = (Boolean) xpp.getProperty(PROPERTY_XML_STANDALONE);
String encoding = xpp.getInputEncoding();
```

I should have better read the [XmlPullParser Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)